Android: How to achieve search bar behavior like in Google Maps?
The default behavior for SearchBar in Material 3 seems to be:
iconified state -> click -> editable state, like in the image below:
From material3
In Google Maps, however, we see a different state, where the design of the editable state is different, and I want something like that in my application:
From Google Maps
Is this a custom component or is there a way to achive this natively?

Have you checked out the Maps SDK for Android? They have an Autocomplete Widget ready. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/android-sdk/autocomplete
